# JDBC Connection with SQL Server using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to establish a connection in sql server and JDBC Connector using pyspark in scala framework at jupyter notebook. However, I'm encountering a following error message:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[45], line 31
     24 connProperties = {
     25     "userid": "xxxx",
     26     "password": "xxxx@1234",
     27     "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     28 }
     30 print(jdbc_url)
---> 31 df = ss.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='employees', properties=connProperties)
     32 df.show()
 
File C:\apps\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o186.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
```

Here's the relevant code snippet used for establishing the connection:

```
ss = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkExample").master("local[*]") \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'C:\\apps\\jdbcdriver\\mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()
 

hostname = 'laptop\\sqlexpress'
port = '1433'
database = 'HR'
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(hostname, port, database)
connProperties = {
    "userid": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxx@1234",
    "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

print(jdbc_url)
df = ss.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='employees', properties=connProperties)
df.show()
```

Comment: I think That you need to change the driver part in your code into : ```"driver": "/path/to/sqljdbc.jar"``` , spark is not finding the driver jar